# Drag parent div on button drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I have a button inside div, I make this button dragable, And my div is also dragable. I have some event on div drag which saves current position of div. 
I want to trigger drag of div on button div. Means when i drag button then my div also drag to the same position and save the positions.

here is sample code:-

```
$(".fieldClass").draggable().resizable();
$('#updateButtonId').draggable({cancel:false,drag: function (e, ui) {
      $("#field_1_updateButton").trigger('drag');
}});
```

JSfiddle:-

http://jsfiddle.net/nbt89x5f/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(".fieldClass").draggable().resizable();
$('#field_1_updateButton').draggable({
    cancel: false,
    drag: function (e, ui) {
        $("#updateButtonId").trigger('drag');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working. But why you interchange id's? If we think as logic then i am correct but that's not working. Can you explain that?